# STM32F303 Readout Protection Level 1 - programs do not start at all

Tags: stm32, protection, bootloader

I never protect the FLASH memory but this time it is my client requirement. I have my own bootloader and the application ready. Everything works fine if the protection level is zero. But if I switch it (it does not matter if I use ST-LINK utility or it is done from the bootloader) to the Level 1 the program just do not work. I know that is ridiciolus to say "program does not work" - but during the tests I wrote simple LED blinking program. It only enables the GPIO clock and toggles the LED. It works fine on level 0, but stops working on Level1. As I understand switching from level 0 to 1 or 2 does not erase the FLASH (it does in the opposite direction). I cant take a look inside as any debug interfaces are disabled.

Boot 0 is connected via 10k resistor to the GND.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a link to the datasheet for your device.

Comment: as per Application note AN4701 on st.com website   `When the read protection level 1 is activated, no access (read, erase, and program) to Flash memory or backup SRAM can be performed via debug features` same for level 2 ..... you have to program the chip first, then switch levels ... are you by chance switching level and then programming it?

Comment: it also says that you have to boot from flash

Comment: @jsotola it is obvious. If something is write protected, it has to be programmed first :)

Comment: And protected after programming

Comment: Just to make sure you didnt misunderstand anything: ROP 2 is irreversible. So I advise you to insert some way to uodate the main program in your bootloader.

Comment: @Jan Dorniak thank you - but I know how it works. I have found the solution - you can read it in my answer.

Comment: Ive seen you found the solution. Just that your question could be misunderstood as ROP 2 being reversible. And AFAIK regular flash writes work even with ROP.

Comment: And your answer was something new to me since we always program ROP with the debugger - never from code.

Comment: `could be misunderstood as ROP 2` I did not write about the removal of the protection only about the seting

Comment: In my bootloader: 1. Denug stage - it is not protecting the memory making debug possible. In any other modes if the there is no protection bootloader sets it.

Answer (score 3):

Silly thing. After setting the protection level ***Power On Reset*** is needed. No other reset type resets the micro. After the power on reset everything works fine. (only one POR needed of course after the protection level change).

It is in the RM - I have not noticed it

> If the read protection is set while the debugger is still connected
>   through JTAG/SWD, apply a POR (power-on reset) instead of a system
>   reset.